# Swift 2.0 drag uiview out of uitable

Tags: swift

I would like to create an item store similar to a game like diablo, that you can drag and drop items from one UIView to another. In my scenario I used a table to hold the items and added an event to the cells for drag and drop.

It works but my issue is that i can't move the object out of the visible space from the table.  As soon as I move the item farther from the border of the table the UIView became invisible.

I assume that I have to create a copy of the table cell and attach it to the superview. But as soon as I do that I loose the control of the UIView and cannot longer drag.

I looked at this example: https://github.com/mmick66/KDDragAndDropCollectionView which addresses my needs but it is way to complicated and contains some bugs.

I wonder if there is another way to easily attach the UIView of a cell to the ViewController and  allow to drag it around ?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("itemrow", forIndexPath: indexPath)
   cell.addTarget(self, action: "move:event:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDragInside)

   return cell}

func move(btn : UIButton, event :UIEvent)
{
    let touch = event.touchesForView(btn)!.first

    let previousLocation : CGPoint = touch! .previousLocationInView(btn)
    let location : CGPoint = touch! .locationInView(btn)
    let delta_x :CGFloat = location.x - previousLocation.x
    let delta_y :CGFloat = location.y - previousLocation.y

    btn.center = CGPointMake(btn.center.x + delta_x,
        btn.center.y + delta_y);

    if chk(btn, target: basket){
        print “yu bought it”
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with targeting iOS9 UICollectionView now has 'free' drag to rearrange functionality.

This post has an introduction to the methods that you'll need to implement: http://nshint.io/blog/2015/07/16/uicollectionviews-now-have-easy-reordering/

It's using a basic flow layout with a single 'section'. I'm not 100% clear the layout you're wanting to create, but potentially it sounds like it could also be a flow layout but with 2 or more separate sections to represent the areas you want to drag and drop objects into.

There are a few steps involved, in terms of support and flexibility, and stability it's the option I'd choose!

Comment: wow this great.. Didn't know about the improvements to the UICollectionView. I am going to use this. Thanks!!